# Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I'm familiar with using AsyncTask in Android: create a subclass, call execute on an instance of the subclass and onPostExecute is called on the UI thread or main thread. What's the equivalent in swift??

Comment: Re your tags: GCD is not "greatest common divisor" :)

Comment: since *I* am not familiar with Android, please try to explain exactly what you want to achieve without too many cross-references!

Comment: Apple provides a "Concurrency Programming Guide" ...

Comment: I think you will be most comfortable using NSOperationQueue, rather than directly with GCD.

Comment: How do I use NSOperationQueue ?

Comment: A better choice is to use NSOperation & NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solves most of my async requirements in Swift:

```
public func background(function: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: function)
}

public func main(function: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: function)
}
```

Then use like:

```
background {
    // I'm in the background
    main {
        // I'm back on Main
    }
}
```

For example:

```
background { [weak self] in
    let result = longOperationToFetchData()
    main {
        self?.data = result.data
        self?.reloadTableView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell an example?

Comment: @J.Arji super late, sorry, but added a quick example and updated answer for latest swift

Answer (score 3):

I think using NSOperationQueue is more elegant and simple. You create a queue:

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue()
```

And create task:

```
let operation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
// Perform your task
}
```

After that, put your task in queue

```
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

That is. In case you want perform UI-related task, using this code block:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
// UI related task
}
```

NSOperationQueue offers you the simple way to set dependency between tasks. For example, you have 4 task, op1, op2, op3, op4. And you want that op1 needs to be done before op2, then you can write like this:

```
op2.addDependency(op1)
```

Then op2 will be fired after op1 done. Since there is no dependency for op3 and op4, it could be done before/or after op2

Comment: your answer is nice, but it works only on apple platform ... libdispatch is currently available on all Darwin platforms, on  linux etc.  and fortunately will be available as a 'standart' part of Swift 3.0 (NSOperation as part of Swift's 3.0 Foundation is not yet implemented). On apple platform +1 for You!

Comment: @J.Arji Actually, a `NSOperation` with a _block_ and `NSOperation` is the closest what you can get to mimic an `AsyncTask` on Android. blocks submitted to dispatch queues, are quite similar - but this facility also serves the purpose to sharply define concurrency constraints and QoS. And _concurrent_ `NSOperations` submitted to a `NSOperationQueue` is something completely different - those execute _asynchronous_ tasks on some private execution context, and not on the queue itself.